# Horizontal scrollbar not visible in Chrome with one line code blocks

Tags: discussion, bug

Apparently, in Chrome, one line code blocks do not show the horizontal scrollbar, making it impossible to read the full code snippet. The only way to read the full block is to get focus on the div and use the keyboard arrows. Also, no cursor is shown, indicating that you have focus. I noticed this while doing a review on the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53744271/4746087).

[image]

```
// this is a very long line of code so it is possible to attempt to verify and replicate the bug for other users since trying to do so with a screenshot is not particularly useful. hopefully, this will be long enough, although you never know.
```

Environment:

**Windows 7: Chrome Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Chrome Version 70.0.3538.110

Comment: Was it this [suggested edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21669064)?  I just looked at the review page and saw the horizontal scroll as well.  I'm using  71.0.3578.80 on Windows 7.  You might want to confirm what version you are using and OS

Comment: Ok, seems I'm on an older version on Windows 7: Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: No repro in Chrome Versión 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64 bits), MacOs 10.14

Comment: No-repro Windows 10 64-bit, Chrome 70.0.3538.110. Maybe you have an extension that's causing issues?

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit), MacOS Mojave, I am running Grammarly, uBlock Origin, and 1password7 X extensions

Comment: Reproduced on MacOS Mojave, Chrome (Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)). Moreover once the scrollbar appears it is not possible to hide it and make it impossible to read, needing a page refresh or something alike. Very annoying